# How do I use the chrome driver in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: google-chrome

The code below is showing an error as if the file does not exist. I can find the `chromedriver.exe` file, but the `.exe` file seems to be non-executable.

These are my commands:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/share/chromedriver')"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

What may cause this dis-functionality?

Comment: Please edit your question with complete Python (?) script you use.

Comment: @N0rbert The code has semicolons. Perhabs it's C++?

Answer (score 36):

You can use `chromium-chromedriver`:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Or download [proprietary ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and use it:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
./chromedriver
```

You need to install selenium python packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-selenium python3-selenium
```

It works with Google's [Getting started python program](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
# or '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver' if you use chromium-chromedriver
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Comment: In my case I didn't need to install any python packages as all I needed was to be able to run chromedriver executable, thank you!!

Comment: Do I need to install `python-selenium` packages if I use` java` to develop?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi obviously not, but I do not know needed package names for Java variant.

Comment: Nice! `chromium-chromedriver` works with `chrome` too.